# How to query elasticsearch for a field value being greater than and less than another field?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a data collection with two fields `y_hat` and `y`.

I want to query it from elasticsearch where `y_hat` is **larger** than `y` value.

How do I do the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Script Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html) from Elasticsearch. Below query will return document only if field `y_hat` value is grater then field `y` value.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": """
            return doc['y_hat'].value > doc['y'].value;
          """
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried this with a must and added range filter for timestamp, it doesn't seems to be working

Comment: @SandeepaKariyawasam can you please update your question and add details like what you have tried and what is not working